# MS-ACCESS 365 Write Conflict Issue

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, office365-apps

After my Access got upgraded to Office 365 i'm starting to get write conflict issue whenever i edit a particular record.  I was not getting this error in 2010 version.

Access database has 1 query used to filter out selected record for editing and 1 form (no subform).  On some records i was able to update, but on some records i'm getting a write conflict.  I'm using a run command `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` to save each record that is updated.  Do you have an idea why changes are saved on some records and why a write conflict on some. There's no other users editing the record.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have issues with msaccess that I cannot explain, I do the following:

1-) Create a new msaccess empty file;
2-) Import all tables / queries / forms, objects to this new msaccess file

It normally solves this kind of issue.

Comment: interesting .. never thought about that.. i will do that scenario maybe its bec i built the db in 2010 version

Comment: So i did several tests. 1.) Repaired the DB - Failed; 2.) Created another version - Failed; 3.) Re-linked the table via ODBC connection and tried to modify the record with write conflict - Failed. Note that i am actually editing the selected row directly. This is puzzling me. it was not an issue in MS Access 2010. hmmm this is only happening on selected data rows.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with some of my clients in the past; Most of the times it is resolved by applying the following instruction:

1. Select File > Options.
2. In the Access Options dialog box, select **Current Database**.
3. Under Application Options, select the **Compact on Close** check box.
4. Select OK.
5. Close and reopen the database for the option to take effect.

More details are here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2

Comment: That didn't work. It behaves the same as some records can be updated and some records has writing conflicts. :(

Answer (score 0):

You might have a bit field in your table that allows NULL, making it a **triple-state field**. Whenever you attempt to save your record, if it is null, it can raise this "Write Conflict" error.

The solution would be either to explicitly **assign a value to it** before saving, or use a **default**. Alternatively, if you have a bound control to it (like a CheckBox), set its Triple State property to False.